# Exception while hitting webservice from a struts based web application

Tags: java, web-services, struts, webservice-client

I have a  proxy based `Web Service Client class(Proxyclient.java)` to hit a webservice deployed in my local server.When i try to hit the weservice via the main function in client class(`Proxyclient.java`) I am able to get the response without any error.but when I am getting a request from a Struts based web application there is no issues untill the request reaches my client class(`Proxyclient.java`). but once it reaches the class in a particular line as below

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory= new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
```

when the execution goes to this line i am getting an error response as below

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
at com.tmb.clientimpl.ProxyClient.checkUserId(ProxyClient.java:18)
at com.tmb.client.action.DetailsFetcher.getStatus(DetailsFetcher.java:14).... more
```

I am having all the required jar files needed for this web service hit. Do i need to have any changes in struts-config.xml or any other jars to be added to rectify the issue..? Kindly help me...

Below is my client class:

```
public class ProxyClient {

public UserIdExistsBean checkUserId(String UserId){
    UserIdExistsBean userIdExistsBean=new UserIdExistsBean();
    try{
    System.out.println("entering before fact");
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory= new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    System.out.println("factory ready");
    factory.setServiceClass(IUserDetails.class);
    factory.setAddress("http://xx.xx.xx:YYYY/UserDetailsService");
    IUserDetails serviceRef=(IUserDetails)factory.create();
    System.out.println("after creating");

    userIdExistsBean=(UserIdExistsBean)serviceRef.checkuserId(UserId);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return userIdExistsBean;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserIdExistsBean userIdExistsBean=new UserIdExistsBean();
    ProxyClient proxy=new ProxyClient();
    userIdExistsBean=proxy.checkUserId("test");
    System.out.println("exists "+userIdExistsBean.isExists());
    System.out.println("response "+userIdExistsBean.getRespString());
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you have the jar with org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean class in your struts web application/WEB-INF/lib directory?

Comment: correct me if i am wrong.If there is no such JAR file in the class path it must also have failed when i was hitting service using the main function alone is in't it?I am facing this error only when i hit this client from struts action class....Thanks for your response

Comment: Are you using an IDE to run Proxyclient with main function? Then without you knowing it must be referencing that jar. Did you verify my question?

Comment: Ok i can und what u are telling, exactly i am using an Eclipse IDE... but i am helpless how to check whether this class is present inside the JAR or not because i have added all the jar files from JBOSS server->Client folder. it has 46 JAR files i donno how to check for this class file among that crowd...

Comment: @user2002631 `jar tf (jar file name) | grep (class name)`

Answer (score 0):

Check any of the jars available in [this](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean) in your Struts Web Application/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: This class is available inside the jar JBOSS/Jboss/jboss-6.1.0.Final/client/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws.jar

Comment: Nope won't work. You must have it inside of Struts Web Application/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Exactly as you say now i placed it inside the classpath but now facing an issue because of this jar XmlSchema.jar

Comment: I placed the XMLSchema.jar inside the class path correctly but then it is not taking that into account...i dono how to refer it...